# printing from csv.reader

Tags: python, csv

This should be an easy one, but I'm having a bit of a brain fart. the CSV maintains a list of four latitude and longitude pairs. Based on the code, if I print row[0] it prints just the latitudes and if I print row[1] it prints the longitudes. How to I format the code to print a specific lat/lon pair instead? Say.. The second lat/lon pair in the CSV.

```
import csv

with open('120101.KAP.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looping over `reader` gives you each row. If you wanted to get the second row, use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) instead, ignore one and get the second:

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
next(reader)  # ignore
row = next(reader)  # second row
print row           # print the second row.
```

You can generalise this by using the [`itertools.islice()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to do the skipping for you:

```
from itertools import islice

reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
row = next(islice(reader, rownumber))  # skip to index rownumber, read that
print row
```

Take into account that counting starts at 0, so "second row" is `rownumber = 1`.

Or you could just read *all* rows into a list and index into that:

```
reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
rows = list(reader)
print rows[1]  # print the second row
print rows[3]  # print the fourth row
```

Only do this (loading everything into a list) if there are a limited number of rows. Iteration over the reader only produces one row at a time and uses a file buffer for efficient reading, limiting how much memory is used; you could process gigantic CSV files this way.

Comment: This worked just fine, is there any way to have the print statement print say just

48.400006749152,-71.083320495196 

as oppose to 

['48.400006749152,-71.083320495196']

Comment: @dpalm - `print 
','.join(rows[1])` or `print ','.join(row)`, depending on which example you use.